# Can you cast a void pointer to a struct to a specific struct type at runtime?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, void

I have a struct defined like this:

```
struct GameState {
    int score;
    int moves;
    bool won;

    void *metadata;
};
typedef struct GameState GameState;
```

The metadata pointer will point to another struct of a type decided at runtime.  For example it might be:

```
struct KlondikeMetadata{
    bool draw3;
    int drawcount;
};
typedef struct KlondikeMetadata KlondikeMetadata;
```

Or maybe:

```
struct FreeCellMetadata{
    int reserveCells;
};
typedef struct FreeCellMetadata FreeCellMetadata;
```

The actual metadata struct used depends on the game the user is playing.  99% of the time this isn't a problem because I know what game the user is playing.  However, there are cases where I don't (and can't) know this.

My question is, is there a way to determine or specify the correct metadata type at runtime?

For example if I could add a property to the GameState struct indicating that the metadata value is of type KlondikeMetadata and use that to cast the metadata to that type, I think I'd be golden.  Is there a way to do this?  Is there a way to specify a type and cast a variable at runtime in C?

Comment: It just occurred to me that I could simply have value to indicate the type of the struct 1:KlondikeMetadata, 2:FreeCellMetadata.  And then I could switch on that value and in each case cast (with static code) to the correct type.

Comment: If it's only one of two well known types, a `union` might be nicer than using a `void *` plus casts.  THis requires the same bookkeeping, of course.

Comment: Interesting. I wasn't aware of unions before now. Thanks.  In the end there will (hopefully) be dozens of these metadata structs.  Either way (union or void) it seems like about the same amount of work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're going to have to encode it yourself.

The easiest solution is to declare an enumeration:

```
typedef enum {
 GameType_Klondike,
 GameType_FreeCell,
} GameType;
```

then add a field of that type before the pointer:

```
GameType game_type;
void     *metadata;
```

Of course, this means you're going to have to *set* the `game_type` field when you initialize `metadata`, to remember the type.

You can also go a bit object-oriented, and have the `GameType` be part of the metadata:

```
struct Metadata {
 GameType gametype;
};

struct FreeCellMetadata {
 struct Metadata meta;
 /* rest of fields here */
};

struct KlondikeMetadata {
 struct Metadata meta;
 /* rest of fields here */
};
```

Then you can cast your `void *` to `struct Metadata *`, and inspect the `gametype` field before casting the pointer to the proper type.

For bonus points, use a union:

```
struct Metadata {
 GameType type;
 union {
 struct KlondikeMetadata klondike;
 struct FreecellMetadata freecellL;
 } game;
};
```

Again, of course this requires you to maintain the data, i.e. when you initialize a `struct KlondikeMetadata` you must remember to set its `gametype` field, and so on.

Comment: I was just thinking this, actually.  You said it much more eloquently. Thanks!